# Node.js - PM2 how to specify interface/IP

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have 2 interfaces/IPs and I would like to launch pm2 scripts with 1 of the interface, how can this be done?

For example, I have interfaces/IP 1.1.2.1, 1.2.2.2

I'd like to run 1 script on interface 1.1.2.1 and another script on interface 1.2.2.2

Can this be done?

Comment: How do the scripts take that input? An environment variable? Argument?

Comment: PM2 is just a script runner, but don't control whatever the scripts does. You need to manage everything within the executed programs. Beside this, I don't know how to control wich interface will be used. The localhost will decide the interface by the best routing automatically. Why would you do that?!